# Randomly dying against Rhodes Giant

Tags: emulation, god-of-war, pcsx2

I'm facing a bug in God of War 2. I'm running the game using an ISO in the emulator PCSX2.

When I'm on the first boss, the Rhodes Giant, I go to the catapult and throw a rock on him; afterwards I jump into him and I click all the buttons that show up on screen.

When Kratos hit his eyes with the swords (after I clicked all the correct buttons in a good timing), Kratos just flies away. I know that at this point he should be in another part of the city. But instead, the screen just goes black and the message "You're dead" shows up.

This is the boss:

At 1:30, the boss will throw Kratos far away. That's the part I'm glitching on.

Also, I just read that in the console, it would be due to a problematic disk, and cleaning it would fix. But I'm using an ISO...

Comment: Are you sure part of the button sequence doesn't call for you to mash one of the buttons continuously?

Comment: No it's not, it's just asking me to press Square, 4 times. It's not a sequence.

Comment: It's helpful to include the emulator's version number when reporting issues.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently there was something wrong with the emulator.

I installed another version of PCSX2 and I noticed that the original version wasn't showing cutscenes. The new version is showing cutscenes, and after the problematic part in the question, there was a cutscene which wasn't being reproduced. This is probably what was causing the glitch.